# Firebase JS - getToken() does not return a token

Tags: javascript, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have the following code, based on [Google's Documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/js/client):

```
var config = {
    apiKey: "XX",
    authDomain: "XX",
    databaseURL: "XX",
    storageBucket: "XX",
    messagingSenderId: "XX"
};
firebase.initializeApp(config);

const messaging = firebase.messaging();

messaging.requestPermission()
.then(function() {
    console.log('Notification permission granted.');
    messaging.getToken()
    .then(function(currentToken) {
        if (currentToken) {
            console.log(currentToken);
        } else {
            console.log('No Instance ID token available. Request permission to generate one.');
        }
    })
    .catch(function(err) {
        console.log('An error occurred while retrieving token. ', err);
    });
})
.catch(function(err) {
    console.log('Unable to get permission to notify. ', err);
});
```

Strangely enough, the `then` function of `messaging.getToken()` is never called. The console does display `Notification permission granted.`, but after that, it stays quiet (i.e. I don't get any errors either).

Am I doing something wrong?

**EDIT:** It should be noted that I'm trying to implement this in a Chrome extension.

Comment: I think Chrome extensions don't have service workers so this should throw an error.

Comment: Hi! You resolve this problem?

Answer (score 9):

I have the same problem, and I spend more than 6hours to solve this problem. You need to create dummy "firebase-messaging-sw.js"(empty file) file in home directory.

My html page location is "**http://localhost:56050/Notification/index.html**"

and my **firebase-messaging-sw.js** is "**http://localhost:56050/firebase-messaging-sw.js**"

Comment: I am able to get the token in firefox but not in chrome. It does not even throw me an error. I think it gets timed out. Any solution?

Answer (score 3):

After I made a change to my "*firebase-messaging-sw.js*" script, I found that the  "*messaging.getToken().then(function(currentToken) {*" wouldn't return.

I went into Chrome's "*Developer Tools*" -> "*Applications*" -> "*Service Workers*" (as shown in the image below) and *Unregistered* the old service worker. After that the "*messaging.getToken().then(function(currentToken) {*" returned okay.

Another issue that I had was that I initially had **two** Firebase projects on my one domain name, which isn't permitted due to limitations with SSL certificates.

[image: Stop and Unregister an existing Firebase Messaging Service Worker in Chrome's Developer Tools]

Answer (score 2):

For me, the clue was to run client and api on HTTPS with self-generated localhost SSL certificate. Then, my `getToken()` started resolving.

It's even in documentation:

> The FCM SDK is supported only in pages served over HTTPS. This is due
>   to its use of service workers, which are available only on HTTPS
>   sites.

It would be helpful if `getToken()` would reject in this situation instead of just hanging forever.

Answer (score 0):

One important note for everyone. 
You have to run it on local server like nginx or apache and to put `firebase-messaging-sw.js` file as mentioned before me.
So I have files *index.html* and `firebase-messaging-sw.js` in root folder.

Comment: What if I want to keep my service worker files in a seperate folder?

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to configure your `firebase-messaging-sw.js` in the root of your project, you can use the `useServiceworker` method. E. g.:

```
messaging.useServiceWorker('pathToYourSW');
```